# Vuetify badge is not showing - commented out in compiled code

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

So I tried to implement [this example for a v-badge](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/badges#customization-options) from vuetify and it is simply not showing in the DOM:

```html
<v-badge bordered color="error" icon="mdi-lock" overlap>
    <v-btn class="white--text" color="error" depressed>
        Lock Account
    </v-btn>
</v-badge>
```

Then I compared the source code of the working example on the vuetify website with the compiled source code of my example:

Working example on vuetify website:
[image: working example on vuetify website]

Not working example in my vue instance:
[image: Not working example in my vuet instance]

Notice the absence of the `v-badge__wrapper` span. Instead of that there is only an empty comment: `<!---->`

Any idea why? And how to fix this?

Comment: what is the version of your vuetify ?

Comment: That comment is basically added by Vue as a placeholder for an `v-if`. You might try upgrading Vuetify. If that doesn't solve your problem, simply let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be vuetify version issue, please upgrade your vuetify version. I solved it also by just upgrading it.